# inserting a random number into an array where each value is being entered through a for-loop

Tags: c++, arrays, random, for-loop, cout

```
//Encryption of pass-phrase
char passReverse(char usrPass[]){
    char newPass[pSize];
    int value;
    int randNum;
    int rand_NumOut;

    //Random number generation
    srand(time(0));
    randNum = rand();
    rand_NumOut = ((randNum %12)+2);
    //Reversing array for-loop
    for (int i=0; i<pSize && usrPass[i] != '\0'; i++){
        char letter = usrPass[i];
        newPass[i] = letter;
        int maxVal = strlen(usrPass);
        if (maxVal >=0){
            newPass[i] = usrPass[(maxVal-1)-i];
        }
        cout << newPass[i];
        value = i;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Ideally the `rand_NumOut` would be placed in newPass[] immediately after the last loop.

The problem I have run into is that when placed in the `for`-loop, of course, `rand_NumOut` is placed after every char in the array, and when outside of the loop, I can't place it in the array's content.

Suggestions?

Comment: If the password was "password" and the random number was "x", would you want the output to be "drowssapx"?

Comment: correct. it reverses the user entered phrase fine, so far, and I want rand_NumOut to be placed at the end of newPass[]

Comment: pSize is a const = 101
included near my header, but not in this portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the end of the **for** loop simply add the lines

```
if(usrPass[i+1]=='\0')
{
//code to insert rand_NumOut
//output rand_NumOut
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are better ways of reversing a string, but aside from that, you are discarding `newPass` at the end of the function when you return the length of the `usrPass`, so it doesn't really matter that you're not appending `rand_NumOut` to the `char` array.

If you just want to send the random number to stdout, then add `cout << rand_NumOut;` before the `return` statement.

Perhaps a better approach would be to use C++'s `std::string` class:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string passReverse(const std::string& userPass)
{
    srand(time(0));
    const int randNum = rand();
    const int rand_NumOut = randNum % 12 + 2;

    std::string reversed(userPass.rbegin(), userPass.rend());

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << reversed << rand_NumOut;
    return oss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << passReverse("password") << std::endl;
}
```

[See it run!](http://ideone.com/btWRl)